# mysql inserting to datetime not outputing correct time

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, format

I want to save to database a given date with this format:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

Using datetime datatype, it outputs:

```
2012-10-29 00:18:14
```

To check if it gives the correct output, I add to my table a timestamp which returns the current date and time of the insertion/update, it returns:

```
2012-10-29 07:18:14
```

I  suspect that there is something wrong with my format.

Comment: additional: when i used date('Y-m-d h:i:s') format, the ouput is 2012-10-29 12:34:16. the site im currently developing is in localhost only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like a timezone issue.

you can use `date_default_timezone` or the `date.timezone` ini setting to have PHP use the same timezone as MySQL.

you can see the MySQL timezone with:

```
select @@session.time_zone;
```

Comment: thank you so much. BIG HELP. btw, when i paste **select @@session.time_zone;**, it returns a word **SYSTEM** and didnt gave my a timezone.

Answer (score 0):

you definitely want to use this format: `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`  according to php manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) - "H" is used for 24 hour time format, "h" is used for 12 hour format, mysql will use a 24hr clock.  MySQL standard format is "Y-m-d H:i:s"

However, you are getting hit with timezone here.  I bet you are 7 hrs from UTC.  try setting your timezone first:

`date_default_timezone_set('UTC');` or whatever timezone you want.

Comment: yes, it was really timezone issue. thank you for you response. i just added this code http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/12/CodeIgniter-on-PHP-5.3 to the main index of the site. btw im currently using code igniter.

Answer (score 0):

`TIMESTAMP` is stored in `UTC (GMT)` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html while `DATETIME` is not, hence your difference.